# Convert an array of ints to an array of characters

Tags: arrays, char, int

I'm trying to create a method that converts an int array to a char array, but I can't get the return statement right. It doesn't compile.

Here's the code:

```
public char [] getLetterGrades() {       
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {

        if      (scores[i] >= 90)   ch = 'A';
        else if (scores[i] >= 80)   ch = 'B';
        else if (scores[i] >= 70)   ch = 'C';
        else if (scores[i] >= 60)   ch = 'D';
        else                        ch = 'F';       
    }
    return ch;
}
```

I tried making ch into a char array but it led to even more errors. Moreover, getLetterGrades() must be an array.

Comment: Please add a tag indicating what language this is. Don't assume it's obvious. And if it doesn't compile, include any error message in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
char[] ch = new char[scores.length];
```

and

```
ch[i] = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you. It has now compiled.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing scores as a parameter, and you're not adding anything into an array, so currently you are returning a char

Comment: We're specifically told not to use any parameters.